# How do I enable IntelliSense for Firebase in VS Code?

Tags: firebase, visual-studio-code

How do I get IntelliSense for Firebase in VS Code like in this video:  https://youtu.be/sKFLI5FOOHs?t=2m13s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the beginning of the video the guy says that he is going to use 2 files: *.sql and *.ts (TypeScript). IntelliSense you asked about is in the second file. So I guess you need to setup TypeScript in your VS Code as described here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following command in your terminal:

```
npm install --save firebase
```

For more details you may refer to https://github.com/waderyan/vscode-js-samples/tree/master/intellisense/typescript-firebase/node_modules/firebase